# Linker don't use library, but I asked to do this

Tags: linux, linker, makefile, cmake

I have a very annoying problem.

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/TheBdfhjkGame
cd /home/user/projekt/thebdfhjkgame-ipp/build/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/eventReceiver.cpp.o \
  CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/game.cpp.o \
  CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/window.cpp.o CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/player.cpp.o \
  CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/object.cpp.o CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/benny.cpp.o \
  CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/bullet.cpp.o CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/base.cpp.o \
  CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/powerRelay.cpp.o CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/ai.cpp.o \
  CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/qrc_systray.cxx.o \
  CMakeFiles/TheBdfhjkGame.dir/__/include/moc_window.cxx.o  -o ../../bin/TheBdfhjkGame \
  -L/home/user/projekt/thebdfhjkgame-ipp/build/../lib -rdynamic \
  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 -Wl,-Bstatic -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext -lXxf86vm \
  -lGLU -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -Wl,-Bstatic -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext -lz -lglut -lXmu -lXi \
  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lQtGui -lQtCore -lBulletDynamics -lBulletCollision -lLinearMath \
  -lIrrlicht -Wl,-Bstatic -lXxf86vm -lGLU -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -Wl,-Bstatic -lz -lglut \
  -lXmu -lXi -Wl,-Bdynamic -lQtGui -lQtCore -lBulletDynamics -lBulletCollision \
  -lLinearMath -lIrrlicht -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/projekt/thebdfhjkgame-ipp/build/../lib 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to symbol 'XextAddDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'XextAddDisplay' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6: could not read symbols: Incorrect operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's worth noticing that I've used

```
-rdynamic /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6
```

flag, but linker ask me to

> 'XextAddDisplay' is defined in DSO
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 so try adding it to the linker
>   command line

How I can solve it? The makefile is generated from cmake.

Comment: Hmm, why are you setting -rdynamic in the first place? It's a flag and doesn't take any parameters. It would seem that you expect it to take a parameter of a filename. I'd suspect a simple -lXext is what you need.

Comment: The linker command contain -lXext

Comment: The libraries are a mess; most of them are listed a couple of times, and there are multiple `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` operations.  That doesn't explain the error.  It is behaving as if `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6` is somehow not usable as a shared object.  Normally, on the link line, you'd specify the name without the `.6` and usually as `-lExt` (as, indeed, your code does).  However, I note that the base X11 libraries are coming before libraries such as `-lQtCore`...you probably need to get the basic X11 libraries listed after the framework libraries.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why after? When A depend on B, I should put A before B in the link line?

Comment: Precisely! Libraries such as `-lQtCore` (A) might well depend on `-lXext` (B), so you should put `-lQtCore` (A) before `-lExt` (B) on the link line. There is essentially zero chance of `-lExt` depending on anything in `-lQtCore`; the converse is possible (but I picked the name `-lQtCore` out of the list semi-arbitrarily). I think you need the libraries `-lQtGui -lQtCore -lBulletDynamics -lBulletCollision -lLinearMath -lIrrlicht` listed before your 'basic' X11 libraries `-lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext -lXxf86vm -lGLU -lGL -lz -lglut -lXmu -lXi` (where I hacked that list out of the command line).

Comment: Please fix the title - you asked to do *what*?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if a libA depends on libB, it is enough if libA is linked. But as per the new DSO link change (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/UnderstandingDSOLinkChange) now libA as well as libB needs to be included. They have done this so that when libA releases a new version without the dependency the compile won't break. They want to break it now itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jonathan's comment, this order works perfect:

```
-lQtGui -lQtCore -lQtOpenGL -lQtXml -lXmu -lXt -lXi -lXext -lX11 \
-lGL -lGLU -lm -lglut
```

Also note the order of `-lGL` and `-lGLU` (in newer versions of g++/GCC)